# After Effects Expression: duplicate a layer in runtime

Tags: expression, after-effects

Say I have a circle on the stage. When it runs, I would like to create duplicates of it on the fly and control the position using some logic. Is is possible to duplicate the circle on the fly? I know how to add a new layer using JSX script, but I was wondering if this can be done from timeline expression?

Answer (score 1):

If your circle is a shape layer you can use an expression on the repeater property.

[image: repeater expression]